# How do I fix the bottom line of code in this loop? how do I combine the i value with "player"

Tags: python, loops

I am assigning two cards to each player and I am trying to do this using a loop
I have a list like this

```
player0 = []
player1 = []
player2 = []
```

My problem is with the last line of code, I need to replace the player+i bit because that is what's wrong with it.
playernum is the number of players

```
for i in range(playernum):
    while len(player0) < 2:
        card = random.choice(deck)
        deck.remove(card)
        player+i.append(card)
```

any help is appreciated, as I am new to python.

Comment: You are adding undefined variable to the usually `None` returned value of a function called on an `int`. There is nothing *right* with it.

Comment: You can't create a reference to a variable by writing `player + i`. (You _could_ do so using `eval`, but you must not do that under any circumstances - it is very bad practice.) The conventional way to achieve your goal would be to use a list of lists: something like `players = [[], [], []]`, which you can access with e.g. `player[i].append(card)`. You would also have to update `len(player0)` to `len(players[0])`.